# linking JavaScript to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am at my wits end with linking a javaScript file to my main.html, they are both in the same folder.

I have viewed multiple Stack overflow topics regarding this question, and for some reason none of the solutions solve my answer.

My current code is what I have below:

[main.html]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
   <link rel="javascript" href="jsfile.js">

   <title>JavaScript</title>
 </head>
   <body>
      <div class="Header">
         <h1>JS Basics</h1>
      </div>
   </body>
```

[jsfile.js]

```
document.write("Hello World");
```

This code does not display the "Hello World" message, however if i insert the code directly into the HTML file it does.

I appreciate any and all help on this matter.

Comment: Check your network tab - sounds like the file isn't being linked properly

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content).

Comment: `href` is not the way to include js. You should use `src` instead, and it should be in a `script` element, not `link`. That approach you used is for styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add like following not with link.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just type:

```
<script src="yourJavascriptFilename.js"></script>
```

Most importantly add this line to the bottom of your body tag to avoid your browsing requesting JavaScript to be loaded before displaying your HTML.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using the incorrect link for JavaScript.

Try using this instead
  `<script src="jsfile.js"></script>`